# Polynomial equation with complex coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm working on a simple equation but I'm finding no way. Can somebody solve it?

$$  Z^4 + iZ^3 - Z^2 - iZ + 1 = 0 $$

Comment: multiply by $Z-i$

Comment: Hint: the LHS is $$\sum_{k=0}^4 (-iZ)^k$$

Comment: This is actually an interesting polynomial, but in the future - you should give detail to how you have approached the question so it doesn't seem like you are just throwing the question out just to get an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

As noted in the comments:
$$
(z-i)(z^4+iz^3-z^2-iz+1)=z^5-i
$$

so the solutions of $z^4+iz^3-z^2-iz+1=0$ are the fifth roots of $i$ different from $i$.